# Daily updating home partition from a master to a slave computer

Tags: networking, 18.04

I have Ubuntu running on two computers both wifi connected to my router. I'll call them master and slave. Probably at the end of the day I would like the master to update the slave home partition so that it will be the same as the master home partition. I'm no technical expert and would like to know an easy and simple to understand way to do this. Can the team advise please?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, I backup my Virtual Machines to my server. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
date >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt
printf "VMsync Starting!\n" >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt
rsync -avhP /home/john/VirtualBox_VMs/ john@192.168.0.66:/data/VirtualBox_VMs/ > /home/john/VMupdate.log 2>&1
printf "VMsync Done!\n\n" >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt
exit
```

I'm sure others could do something more elegant but it works fine. The script appends to it's own
logfiles (anacronjobs.txt) and VMupdate.log. You can use tail on VMupdate.log to monitor progress.

I run this using Anacron because its a laptop and is not always on. If your machines are always on you can use cron or systemd timers. When you create the script make sure its executable and obviously amend the locations, user name and ip address to fit your situation.

I've not done this with a home folder between two machines. It will synchronize everything including hidden configuration files which might have unexpected consequences. You might want to copy just the documents folder (plus perhaps a few others) rather than the entire home directory